# Border-radius: 50% vs. border-radius: 999em

Tags: html, css

While exploring the awesome markup of Medium, found an interesting way to make beautiful pill-styled buttons by using border-radius:999em. However this raised a question: why border-radius:50% makes an oval instead of a pill?

Here is a live example: http://codepen.io/evergreenv/pen/ykpBA/

[image: Codepen to illustrate border-radius:50% vs. border-radius:999em]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The border radius property does all it can to mantain same ratio between the overall radius, when you use `border-radius: 999em`, it keeps the same proportions of the smallest corner.

But when you use `border-radius: 50%`, it makes the border set to the proportions of the entire object, assuming x-axis for 50% of the width and y-axis for the 50% of the height of the object, all corners combined make it appear as if the object is circular.

Comment: Percentage in `border-radius` is now widely supported. That last paragraph and blockquote should be removed.

Answer (score 2):

You have a rectangular div.

In A, border-radius rounds every corner 50% of the width/height of the div.

In B, border-radius rounds every corner with the same amount (999em, only relative to size of the font).

Answer (score 1):

Ok it makes an oval by using `border-radius: 50%` because it counts borders of an element from  x and y direction which means by width and height and you have width of 120px and height of 60px so it calculate like this border on x direction means 60px and on y its 30px radius and by combining it make an oval.

while applying css `border-radius:100px` 
it makes

`border-top-left-radius: 100px;
border-top-right-radius: 100px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 100px;`

so you get pill shape.